# How to express a logic sequence of a control circuit operation for a motor control center?

Tags: motor, power-electronics, algorithm

I have a customer to which I need to explain the logic sequence of the operation of the motor control centre's control schematics. The MCC has a complex RVSS unit for which the logic sequence has a moderate difficulty level. However, I tried every possible way in form of excel worksheet and pictorial representation. By pictorial representation I mean this :-
[image]

Ofcourse the above logic is simple and is shown for example.
Using the excel worksheet, I use textual form for every logical sequence (or rung) Example,

1. When the **START** push button is depressed, the coil M is energized and is latched through M XIC **TRUE**.
2. When the **STOP** push button in depressed, the coil M is denergized, thus the M XIC is turned **FALSE**

This becomes a tedious task for vast control schematics, including **RVSS, VFDs and smart overload relays**. Is there any specific way to express the control sequence algorithm the easier way (other than these) ?

Comment: So you need to teach the customer control engineering? Or should they know how to use it?

Comment: @SolarMike We need to explain the flaws in there schematics (furnished by contractors) and help them by providing correct logic, since they have limited to no knowledge about our product operation (like VFD control board or parameters of OL relays)

Comment: So their quality control between them and their contractors is failing as they are producing incorrect logic?

Comment: @SolarMike Sending the logic sequence explaination to the customer is a last resort, when the contractor/customer fails to understand the logic sequence of what I have proposed or pointing out their flaws in their incorrect R&R schematics (markups). So control schematic explaination is quite unusual, but it is necessary for complex schematics.

Comment: Well, when we had to do a custom build for a heating system controller (2 heat sources, 8 demand points) we used ladder diagrams and flow diagrams to show how the control "moved".